# What does the bounty filter box's "Has bounty" do?

Tags: support, bounties, filtering, bountied-tab

[image: bounty filter box]

Not only can't I quite make sense of showing only bountied questions without bounty, de-selecting [does not seem to have any effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=BountyEndingSoon&edited=true) either…

Comment: Did you press the apply filter button? Otherwise nothing gets changed.

Comment: Now you can ask for bounties that don't end soon.

Comment: @Mast I don't understand. What are you telling me?

Comment: You were asking what the box did. I told you what the box did. The box is for filtering (previously) bountied questions regardless of whether they expire soon or are already expired, the 'sorted by' radiobutton is only for sorting. 'Has bounty' should actually be called 'has ever had one or more bounties of which at least 1 was awarded' IIUC.

Comment: @Mast Well, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60832221/5306507) post is on the bounty list when "Has bounty" is selected, even though it has *never* had one or more bounties of which at least 1 was awarded, so I don't think your understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, I said that wrong. Should've been 'has ever had one or more bounties of which at least 1 was awarded *or* currently has active bounty'. Naturally.

Comment: @Mast Right, which then comes back to what that box does on the "bountied" tab where obviously *all* listed posts have an active bounty.

Comment: So the real question is how that tab works. Since you move away from that tab the moment you use a filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters are independent of tabs, which is a good design choice to make storing and choosing filters independent of tab as well, so it does nothing, but it's still logical for it to be there.